# Disable Default background of Actionbar and add custom background

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-appcompat

i am trying to add Custom background to AppCompat action bar. Here is my style

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/top_bar_bg</item>
</style>
```

I am using AppTheme as my Theme. It still shows default dark background. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In res/values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
        <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
               parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        </style>

        <!-- ActionBar styles -->
        <style name="MyActionBar"
               parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
            <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

In res/values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Are you using the latest update of support library v7? If yes, then now action bar color can be also specified using `android:colorPrimary` attribute through the Material Design.